# Logical Issue or Syntax issue with sorting String function

Tags: c++, function, anagram

I'm new to C++ and coding in general. I'm attempting to make a simple program that essentially takes in two words and will tell you if these two words are anagrams or not.I also understand that there is likely a pre-made function to sort a string, like an array however I am trying to grasp the concept itself and hence why I'm attempting to make the function.

Here is a quick snippet of the code I've written so far.

[Snippet of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5X3F.png)

The issue that I'm currently having is that when I call the function to sort the string, the string isn't sorted! Sorry if there is a simple solution to this, I'm fairly new. Is this a logical issue or syntax based? Thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Function Declarations
string sortString(string user_input);

//Program Body
int main()
{
    string user_input_one, user_input_two;
    cout << "Welcome to Sandip's Anagram Checker! \nPlease Input two words that you'd like the check!";
    sortString(user_input_one);
    sortString(user_input_two);
    if (user_input_one == user_input_two)
        cout << "These two words are Anagrams of each other!";
    else
        cout << "These are not Anagrams!";
    return 0;
}

//Function Definations
string sortString(string user_input)
{
    string temp_string = user_input;
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i<user_input.length();i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<user_input.length();j++)
        {
            if (user_input[i] == user_input[j])
            {
                temp_string[i] = user_input[j];
            }
            else if (user_input[i] > user_input[j])
            {
                temp_string[i] = user_input[j];
            }
            else if (user_input[i] < user_input[j])
            {
                temp_string[i] = user_input[i];
            }

        }
    }
    return temp_string;
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Comment: If it's a syntax issue, the compiler will tell you.

Comment: my bad! here's the code, the main thread should be updated.

Comment: What sorting algorithm are you trying to implement? I don't recognize it.

Comment: Essentially a nested for loop that will check the values of each char in the string and order it from lowest to highest, or a-z. Then it will return the resulting string and they will be compared. I don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: Sorting the strings won't help you check if they're palindromes.  Did you mean anagrams?

Comment: My mistake! I mean't anagram, slipped my mind. Thank you for the clarification, will quickly fix that.

Comment: I would suggest not trying to learn multiple things at the same time. Use `std::sort` to implement the anagram checker, and then *separately* try to implement a sorting algorithm.

Comment: Even if your `sortString` function works, you are not using the value returned from it.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear which algorithm you're trying to use.  Is it perhaps [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) or [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Daniel's answer, you don't need a temporary string in the sorting function, just process the passed string and return it. Also consider supporting letter cases as well, you can use [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) from the STL `algorithm` library.

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Add this before looping in your sorting function or after taking inputs in `main`.

```
transform(user_input.begin(), user_input.end(), user_input.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will keep this in mind for my future projects!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues.  You're not actually reading any user input.  You can fix this by adding `cin >> user_input_one >> user_input_two;`.

Your sorting also doesn't work quite right.  It looks similar to [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), so I tweaked it to be a variation of that.  For each character in the string, it goes through the rest of the string and swaps letters if the later one should be first.

```cpp
string temp_string = user_input;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < user_input.length(); i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < user_input.length(); j++)
        {
            if (temp_string[j] < temp_string[i]) {
                swap(temp_string[i], temp_string[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return temp_string;
```

Lastly, as @cigien commented, you aren't using the sorted result.  You can change this by replacing your lines calling `sortstring()` with this:

```cpp
user_input_one = sortString(user_input_one);
user_input_two = sortString(user_input_two);
```

Comment: Yes! That makes sense, thank you so much. I know there wasn't any user input, but that's because I was attempting to figure out how to work around VSCode's output only terminal, and change the settings on CodeRunner. Thank you though, will implement this! I appreciate it. I wasn't aware of the swap function either, I was attempting to replicate that manually and therefore could have possibly been causing the issues and the clarity of the sortString function.